# How to add counting number to a record in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to add a number to specific column in my data:but my @id is static and doesn't change, what do I miss
//that's what I need

```
names
-----
david1
david2
david3
```

//that's my code

```
 DECLARE @var INT 
SET @var = 0 
update [dbo].[ContactBase]
set FirstName = 'david  + convert(varchar(10),@var )    
set  @var =@var + 1;
```

Comment: An ID should never change. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL Server I suppose? With SQL questions you should always tag the DBMS used.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I change my code to make it more clear the id is a var

Comment: I've tagged your request with SQL Server for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following.

```
;
WITH    CTE
          AS (SELECT    FirstName
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1
                                                    )) RN
              FROM      ContactBase
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    CTE

;
WITH    CTE
          AS (SELECT    FirstName
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1
                                                    )) RN
              FROM      ContactBase
             )
    UPDATE CTE
    SET FirstName = FirstName + CAST(RN AS VARCHAR(10))
```

The first call just shows you the output from the cte, the second one actually handles updating.

Also using the row number option you can also seperate out by names to give you david1,david2,Jon1,Jon2,etc quite simply. Is a handy way of de-duping data.

```
DECLARE @ContactBase AS TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @ContactBase
        (FirstName)
VALUES  ('David'),('David'),('David')

SELECT * FROM @ContactBase

;WITH    CTE
          AS (SELECT    FirstName
              ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1
                                                    )) RN
              FROM      @ContactBase
             )
    UPDATE CTE
    SET FirstName = FirstName + CAST(RN AS VARCHAR(10))

    SELECT * FROM @ContactBase
```

Comment: its close but I get david1, david10, david100 and not david1 david2

Comment: Check your implementation.  I've posted a standalone version and I'm seeing the results that I expected. Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want... You want to

- Add a number (id) at the end of FirstName ?
- Do a loop who add element in you database with new id ?

Comment: add a changing number to the end of FirstName

Comment: in your code, their is a " ' " missing (`set FirstName = 'david`) and use `CONCAT(FirstName, convert(varchar(10),@var))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the numbers.

```
update n 
set firstname = 'david' + cast(num as varchar(10))
from
 (select firstname, row_number() over (order by firstname) as num from dbo.contactbase) n;
```

REXTESTER demo: http://rextester.com/CZDJ47320